# How can I get all users images in template,django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So , I'm trying to write blog in Django and now I have problem with comments. 
Below each post I have users comments , with comment author name , image and comment.

Comments class:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name= 'upser')
    image = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile , related_name='im')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-timestamp',)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='oser')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

So , I have comments class connected with UserProfile class in which I have user's image.

That's what I have in template to display all comments:

```
 {% for comment in comments %}
            <li>

            <div class="media" style="margin-top: 10px">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src={{ MEDIA_ROOT }}/{{ PLACE FOR USER'S PICTURE }} alt="" width="80px" height="80px" >
                    </a>

                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ comment.author}}
                            <small>{{ comment.timestamp }}</small>
                        </h4>
                            {{ comment.body }}
                    </div>
                </div>


            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

And question ,how can I access user image from template if I have Comments object there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need the `image` attribute that is a foreign key to the `UserProfile` model.

You can just do that in the template:
`{{comment.author.oser.picture.url}}`

This does the following:

Get the comment, get its author, go to its "oser" attribute which is the corresponding `UserProfile` and then get the picture attribute's image url.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your model looks somewhat strange to me, or it doesn't fit so much your description:

you have a "Comments" class (shouldn't it be "Comment", as it contains a single comment?) which has a body, author, timestamp, the post it belongs to... fine. But the field you named "image" is actually the user_profile, right? Also, a OneToOneField would imply a 1 to 1 relationship between a Comment(s) object and a UserProfile... most probably not what you want!

Actually you have the author already, so that is enough to get the picture... so author is a user -> user_profile -> picture. Or do i understand your Model & question incorrectly?